# Insert a UIView between intercecting other UIView(s)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, position

I have a screen which contains 9 UIViews (imagine 3x3 table with views, 3 views for each row) that takes all the screen.
I drag a UIView and then move it around, then I want as soon as touchEnded to place it somewhere inbetween the other intercepting UIViews and have again a 3x3 screen with the UIViews now of course reorder with the dragged UIView where I (somehow) put it.

Everything is going great except the reordering of the UIViews. I need a way to find out I guess with what other UIView is intersecting most (the biggest areas are intersecting inbetween all UIViews that draggable UIView frame has) and reorder all the UIViews with new positions.

All of these are happening in the superview which own all the views and has a NSMutableArray with the UIViews. I dont want to move the objects in the list but find a solution through frames.

Imagine you have 9 cards in a table and changing them position in this 3x3 grid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just use the view.center to determine if the point intersects the other view. If they are not overlapping then center will only hit one view. you can use the following code to get the point within the intersecting view.

```
CGPoint centerInOtherView = [thisView convertPoint:thisView.center toView:otherView];
```

then you can test intersection with the following code.

```
if ([otherView pointInside:centerInOtherView withEvent:nil]){
    // Do Something
}
```

at that point you know that your dragging view's center is withing the view you are testing

You can also rearrange your view as so.

```
UIView *mySuperView = [thisView superview];
NSUInteger index = [[[mySuperView subviews] indexOfObject:otherView];
[thisView removeFromSuperview];
[mySuperView insertSubview:newView atIndex:index];
```

Comment: I understand the approach, but i cant get it right positioned, first its so difficult to enter the if condition and in that if i try to give new frame values of the otherView in the draggable view end then next frame values to otherView. But it gets in with luck...

Comment: Add the new code to the mix. the setting of the frame is up to you. based on your calculation. You may have a set of frames that have the frame for each item on the screen. Or you may want to calculate it. but as for adding them in the order you want. this code should help.

Comment: are you testing each of the views in the parent that are not the view your dragging.